# Hessian Matrix Principal Minor and Convexity

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, locally-convex-spaces, hessian-matrix

Say I have a Hessian Matrix:

$\begin{matrix}
  0 & 1 \\
  1 & 0
 \end{matrix}$

The principal minor for 2x2 symmetric matrix are:

$D_1=0$,        $D_2=ac-b^2$

which are: $D_1=0, D_2=-1$.

So, one is negative, one is equal to 0. can I say this function is neither convex and concave ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x_0$ is a point of the domain $D$ of a $C^2$ - function $f$ and if

$H_f(x_0)=\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1 \\
  1 & 0
 \end{pmatrix}$, then $H_f(x_0)$ is indefinite.

Thus, $f$ is  neither convex nor concave on $D$